# How to get the total row count for GWT CellTable pagination in

Tags: java, gwt, pagination, gwt-celltable

I'm trying to implement paging in a CellTable but it's currently showing "1-10 of 10" records instead of "1-10 of 1000" records. I'm not sure where I can update the total record count. My AsyncDataProvider looks like this:

```
    AsyncDataProvider<OutletSearchVO> latestProvider = new AsyncDataProvider<OutletSearchVO>() {

        @Override
        protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<OutletSearchVO> display) {
            final int start = display.getVisibleRange().getStart();
            int length = display.getVisibleRange().getLength();
            AsyncCallback<List<OutletSearchVO>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<OutletSearchVO>>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<OutletSearchVO> result) {
                    updateRowData(start, result);
                }
            };
            // The remote service that should be implemented
            service.getOutletPage(start, length, callback);

        }
    };
```

The SQL I'm using to grab the records is similar to this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT outlet_id,
           outlet_name,
           image,
           ROWNUM rn
      FROM (  SELECT outlet_id outlet_id,
                     account_name outlet_name,
                     image_score image,
                FROM outlets)
            ORDER BY OOI.created_on DESC, OOI.account_name))
WHERE rn > ? AND rn < ?
```

The question marks are replaced by the start and end range in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `updateRowCount` from within your `AsyncDataProvider` (similar to how you call `updateRowData`), which means you have to ask your server for that count (or at least an approximation, and then choose whether you pass a `true` or `false` as the second argument to `updateRowCount`).

Of course, you can also call `updateRowCount` from outside the `onRangeChange`, particularly if you can know upfront how many rows you'll have, and that number is not going to change that much.